# How to change color of enumerate?

Tags: beamer, color, enumerate

I am making a presentation in Beamer and want to change the color of the numbers in enumerate. I tried using `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}{bg=blue}` but it didn't work. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you only need to change the `f`ore`g`round colour? Or why are you using `bg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to change the colour, you want to use `\setbeamercolor` instead of overwriting the complete template.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=red}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item test
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```